# How to wait for a click in c#

Tags: c#, events, click

I am currently taking a beginner's class in c#. We missed 2 consecutive classes because the teacher couldn't be there. So we didn't really see what we needed to do this. He said to just go see on MSDN, but that is usually way too complicated for me. So here is my problem:

I have to create a "Simon Says" program. Here is my current code (sorry for the French variables):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const byte LIMITE = 255;
    const byte LIMITEBOUTON = 5;
    byte[] _abyBouton = new byte[LIMITE];
    Random _rand = new Random();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Blinks the Button. Works correctly.
    void AnimerBouton(Button btnBouton, Color Cocoleur)
    {
        btnBouton.BackColor = Color.Black;
        btnBouton.ForeColor = Color.White;
        Update();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // C'est inscrit en miliseconde
        btnBouton.BackColor = Cocoleur;
        btnBouton.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        Update();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // C'est inscrit en miliseconde
    }

    private void btnDémarrer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Creates an array with the 255 eventual moves.
        for (byte byIndex = 0; byIndex <= LIMITE - 1; byIndex++)
        {
            _abyBouton[byIndex] = (byte)_rand.Next(1, LIMITEBOUTON);
        }

        for (byte byIndex = 0; byIndex <= LIMITE - 1; byIndex++)
        {
            //Takes care of the current progress in the game.
            for (byte byIndex2 = 0; byIndex2 <= byIndex; byIndex2++)
            {
                switch (_abyBouton[byIndex2])
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            AnimerBouton(btn1, Color.Green);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        {
                            AnimerBouton(btn2, Color.Red);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        {
                            AnimerBouton(btn3, Color.Yellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        {
                            AnimerBouton(btn4, Color.Cyan);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                //Wait to see if the click is correct. No idea how to do this.
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

So I have to wait for the user to click a button and see if it is the correct one. I looked around and it was talking about events, but I couldn't grasp what I needed to do. I would appreciate some help on how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the designer, on the properties window, click the lightning bolt icon. You will get a list of events for the selected control. Make sure the `btnBouton` control is selected, and find the `Click` event in the list. You should see `btnDemarrer_Click` in the drop down list. Select it. Now when the button is clicked, it should call your `btnDemarrer_Click` handler.

When you have not already written a handler, you can double-click the event in the list, and it will generate the method skeleton for you automatically. You can also double-click the control itself to generate the default event handler for that control. (In the case of buttons, I think the default event is the click event.)

Answer (score -2):

If you want a particular method to wait until some work is done, you could look into [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx). An *extremely* simplified example might help you get on the right track:

```
using System.Threading;

public static AutoResetEvent arEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

static void Main()
{
    DoWork();
    arEvent.WaitOne();  //WaitOne() "pauses" Main and waits for some work to be done.
    DoWork();
    arEvent.WaitOne();
}

static void DoWork();
{
    //Some work is done here.
    arEvent.Set(); //This lets Main() continue where it left off.
}
```

Using this, you could have `btnDémarrer_Click` wait for the user input then continue on after the user has done his clicking.

Comment: Not sure how this applies to the question asked, and not sure it makes any sense, anyway. `DoWork` is running in the same thread as the calls to `WaitOne`.

Comment: @AndrewBarber The question asks how to wait for a specific event (namely, a button click) to occur. The commented line at the bottom of his code is where he wants to wait for the user input. I'm assuming after the input is received, `btnDémarrer_Click` will continue and check the input against the correct answer.

As for the example, it was extremely simplified to get the point across. :)

Comment: Probably the OP created the handler manually without subscribing the event.